# When was my VM in VirtualBox created?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Is it possible to determine when a VM in virtual box was created? I am looking at the virtual hard disk in the host operating system and the date created property is showing the last time I launched the VM.

Maybe there's a way inside the operating system - it's Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Comment: What's the VirtualBox version you're using?

Comment: Strange - on Windows the "Created Date" for the .vhd file correctly reflects the date I created the VM (2013 in my case). (running latest 5.x version)

Comment: In this case, it's v5.0+ and I'm asking from Mac OSX, inspecting properties in Finder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways from the system running in VM:

1.Creation of filesystem:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created:'
```

2. Installer logs

```
ls -lt /var/log/installer
```

3. Files in boot directory

```
ls -lt /boot
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-what-date-ubuntu-was-installed

Comment: Options 1 and 2 reveal a date in the vicinity of what I'm looking for. None of the timestamps from option 3 match those from options 1 and 2.

Comment: In that case something happened to boot directory, but given that filesystem creation and installer logs points to same date, that leaves no doubt about date

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information you need from the VirtualBox log files. For Ubuntu, they are located at:

`$HOME/.VirtualBox/Machines/<vm name>/Logs`

Comment: This VM generates a large volume of logs to dig through. I can't find a useful timestamp out of it. Good to know about though...

Comment: AFAIK, VBox's logs haven't such information that OP looking for - data&time of VM creation